# Weird behavior when using esvect and caption together

Tags: math-mode, captions

I was working on this file : (to be considered as MWP, a minimal working problem)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% ###########################################
% PACKAGES STANDARDS
% ###########################################
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
% ###########################################
% PACKAGES MATHS
% ###########################################
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[d]{esvect}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% ###########################################
% Nouveaux packages à ajouter + param
% ###########################################
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=\'Equation]{myeq}
\captionsetup[myeq]{labelfont=tt}
% ###########################################
% MACROS à ajouter
% ###########################################
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccsc}{arccsc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argsh}{argsh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argth}{argth}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argch}{argch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argcoth}{argcoth}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arsech}{arsech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsch}{arcsch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rg}{rg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sp}{Sp}
% Nouveaux :
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dev}{dev}
\newcommand{\ull}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\newcommand{\grad}{\vv{\mathrm{grad}}}
\newcommand{\rot}{\vv{\mathrm{rot}}}
% Dérivée partielle, droite, et particulaire mise en snippet avec dp comme tabtrigger
\usepackage{ccfonts}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{ccfonts}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}% cmr = Computer Modern Roman
% Macros pour torseur et le déviateur
% Liste des figures à rajouter : Figure 9 + 3D, Figure 10
% Notations : tenseur identité, tenseur nul, déviateur, sigma, tau 
%====================================================
%####################################################
%====================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{myeq}
\begin{equation*} % Torseur statique des efforts de cohésion
\mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{ext}/1}=\left\lbrace{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle \vv*{R}{\mathrm{ext}/1} = \iint_{S_{\mathrm{ext}}}\vv{\sigma}(M,\vv*{n}{\mathrm{ext}})\mathrm{d}S = \iint_{S_{\mathrm{ext}}}\vv*{F}{\mathrm{ext}}\mathrm{d}S\\
\displaystyle\vv*{\mathcal{M}}{\mathrm{ext}/1} = \iint_{S_{\mathrm{ext}}}\vv{GM}\wedge\vv{\sigma}(M,\vv*{n}{\mathrm{ext}})\mathrm{d}S = \iint_{S_{\mathrm{ext}}}\vv{GM}\wedge\vv*{F}{\mathrm{ext}}\mathrm{d}S\\
\end{array}}\right\rbrace_{M}
\end{equation*}
\caption{Torseur statique des efforts de cohésion -- $G$ est le centre de gravité de la section $S$ et $\vv*{n}{\mathrm{ext}}$.}
\end{myeq}
\end{document}
```

I get the following errors :

```
l66: Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }. [...a section $S$ et $\vv*{n}{\mathrm{ext}}$.}]
l66: Paragraph ended before \caption@ydblarg was complete. [...a section $S$ et $\vv*{n}{\mathrm{ext}}$.}]
```

The output looks fine (the errors don't trigger anything in the final pdf) and the error messages disappear when I remove `$\vv*{n}{\mathrm{ext}}$`, which is a command from the [esvect package](https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/esvect/esvect.pdf).

**Can someone explain me why does this happend ?**

Thank you in advance for any suggestions !

Comment: Not very minimal:-)

Comment: Indeed but it produces (at least on my computer) the error

Comment: yes but it's much easier for peop le debug if you post an example with all unrelates packages removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more reasonable example showing the issue is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% ###########################################
% PACKAGES STANDARDS
% ###########################################
% ###########################################
% PACKAGES MATHS
% ###########################################
\usepackage[d]{esvect}

% ###########################################
% Nouveaux packages à ajouter + param
% ###########################################
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=\'Equation]{myeq}
\captionsetup[myeq]{labelfont=tt}
% ###########################################
% MACROS à ajouter
% ###########################################

% Nouveaux :
%====================================================
%####################################################
%====================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{myeq}

\caption{Torseur statique des efforts de cohésion -- $G$ est le centre de gravité de la section $S$ et $\vv*{n}{\mathrm{ext}}$.}
\end{myeq}
\end{document}
```

This is a "fragile command in moving argument" error. the command `\vv` is apparently not robust so you could use

```
\caption[short form]{Torseur statique des efforts de cohésion --
                $G$ est le centre de gravité de la section $S$
                et $\vv*{n}{\mathrm{ext}}$.}
```

or

```
\caption{Torseur statique des efforts de cohésion --
  $G$ est le centre de gravité de la section $S$ et
  $\protect\vv*{n}{\mathrm{ext}}$.}
```

To get forms that are safe to write to the list of floats.

Comment: This solves the issue. Thank you, I should have edited my post according to your recommandations.

Comment: @Elyo actually I was a bit hard on you as this didn't take a lot of tracing but in other cases if you have to run \tracingall to debug what tex is really doing, extra packages can make it a lot harder and a first step is always simply deleting preamble lines, checking teh problem still occurs.

Comment: +1 for showing compassion.